# how long would oxidation of ammonia solution to nitrates take?

Tags: biotechnology, biosynthesis

A hot topic among amateur chemists is making nitric acid from ammonia. While not as useful, im interested in making nitrate salts from ammonia as well.

A simple idea is to just infect ammonia solution with soil bacteria and add some fresh grass as source of other necessary nutrients for bacteria. If kept at optimal temperature, how long can i except the process of forming ammonium nitrate to take?

Comment: Hi, maybe tell us how far you got and where your research got stuck. A lead can be to search for COMMOX (COMplete AMMonia OXidiser), they do the whole process from ammonia to nitrate.

Comment: haven't started the experiment yet, i just wanted to know whether it would take days, week, or months